# Bcrypt hashing not supported in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, bcrypt

I am working with Laravel 4, when i try to create a Hash i get this exception

> Bcrypt hashing not supported

Knowing that my `PHP version is 5.3.8` and i shouldn't upgrade it. Also `mcrypt` on `phpinfo()` is activated!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the exact version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel need PHP >= 5.4 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's too late to post the answer but the solution was : PHP should be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BCrypt class written in PHP that you can use. It does NOT require any special PHP version. Im not sure about performance of any native hashing libraries, but this one might need a second to hash.

It can be found here:
[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)